# I am using pickle in Python, and trying to pickle information to a .txt file. It is putting weird things in the text file

Tags: python, text-files, pickle

I am trying to make a program that cleans music. It asks you to enter the URL and pickles it to a text file. After having errors with playing the video, I looked at the text file. This is what was in it even though I only entered a youtube link.

```
€]q (X    qX$   https://youtube.com/watchqtYmDMzhIToqe.
```

For some reason, it added extra characters to the text file

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Pickle is a binary format.  You shouldn't expect that a pickled file when interpreted as a text file is human readable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Pickle does not write text files, it writes binary format files. You should not write to a `txt` file, open it as text and expect the result to make sense.

If you want to write to a `txt` file you should use:

```
string = 'text to be written'
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(string)
```